# Returning/getting an output from Twit's client.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I have this code in node.js and I am using Twit:

```
var output = "Output: "
client.get('search/tweets', {q: "apple", count:5},
    function(err, data, response){
        for (var index in data.statuses) {
            var tweet= data.statuses[index];
            console.log('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' + tweet.text+'\n');
            output += '@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' + tweet.text+'\n'
        }
    })
console.log(output);
```

The five tweets print to the console just fine but do not get added to the output, all that is printed from `console.log(output);` is `Output:`. Also, this line is printed before the tweets so it must be that the `client.get` function runs parallel to the rest of the script; how can I force it to not do this?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are defining:

```
function(err, data, response){
    for (var index in data.statuses) {
        var tweet= data.statuses[index];
        console.log('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' + tweet.text+'\n');
        output += '@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' + tweet.text+'\n'
    }
})
```

is called a callback. After the `get` function retrieves the data from the server, that callback function is run. If you move `console.log(output);` to inside the function, right below the for loop, it should print what you're expecting. Also, you can't really force it to not run parallel, or you're not supposed to. Server calls are best done asynchronously. Just do what you need to do with the data by calling another function, like handleData, in your callback, like so:

```
function(err, data, response){
    for (var index in data.statuses) {
        var tweet= data.statuses[index];
        console.log('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' + tweet.text+'\n');
        output += '@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' + tweet.text+'\n'
    }
    handleData(data);
})
```

Comment: The code I had would eventually be wrapped up in a method that returns the output and would then be sent to the browser, I suppose the `handleData()` function could do the sending back.